# Not able to connect to SQL Server from R

Tags: rodbc

dbhandle <- `odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};server=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;database=Data;trusted_connection = false;uid = 1234; pwd = 1234")`

I am using the above string to connect to SQL from R but I am getting the below error -

Warning messages:
1:

> In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL
>   Server};serverserver=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;database=Data;trusted_connection =
>   false;uid = 1234; pwd = 1234") :   [RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code
>   18452, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Login
>   failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.

2:  In `odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};server=server=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;database=Data;trusted_connection = false;uid = 1234; pwd = 1234")` :

> [RODBC] ERROR: state 01S00, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL
>   Server Driver]Invalid connection string attribute

3:  In `odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};server=server=xx.xxx.xx.xxx;database=Data;trusted_connection = false;uid = 1234; pwd = 1234")` :

> ODBC connection failed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

> server=server=

duplicate "server="

Just a guess